# мне нужно вывести список всех файлов в Linux

Tags: linux, файловая-система, grep

мне нужно вывести список всех файлов в Linux, и только файлов, начиная с корневого каталога, а после отфильтровать их так, чтобы grep оставил только имена файлов, содержащих слово test(с фильтрацией я может и сам справлюсь, а вот как вывести все файлы я не понимаю)

Comment: ну так ls выводит. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 6):

Найти все обычные файлы, в названии которых есть "test", в корневом каталоге рекурсивно:

```
find / -type f -name "*test*"
```

Comment: Только запускать надо от пользователя root, поскольку не все каталоги в системе доступны для чтения обычным пользователям

Comment: @Сергей-Бондарь, благодарность нужно выражать в виде отмеченного решением